# Expected nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, gcc

I am taking my project from my laptop to another and I encounter an error.
My project runs perfectly on my machine that I use codeblocks.

Now, I try to compile it with catkin and I get an expected nested-name-specifier before "XXX". A code snipet where this error occurs is the following

```
template <class T>
struct convert{
    using to_int = int;
}
```

Outputs

> expected nested-name-specifier before 'to_int'
>
> using-decleration for non-member at class scope
>
> expected ';' before  '='  token

I get this error in multiple lines of the file and at first I thought that it was a compiler issue.
I then updated from gcc 4.6 to 4.8 using [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8) as a guide but I still have the same issues. Is there a specific reason I get this error? If it's not a compiler issue what could it be?

Cheers,

Panos

Comment: Sounds like you didn't activate C++11 mode.

Comment: Did you use `-std=c++11` when you compiled?

Comment: I added the command 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
to my file but now I get the error unrecognized command line option ' -std=c++11'
Does this mean my compiler is still not gcc 4.8?
My gcc --version shows 4.8

Comment: According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) Template aliases/alias declerations are supported in GCC4.7 and later and GCC4.7 and later support `-std=c++11`

Comment: Are you sure cmake is using the right version of GCC?

Comment: How can I change the version of gcc with the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: It turns out I was using g++ instead of gcc with catkin. I updated g++ and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the responses